# How to mocking an insert to dynamodb with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, amazon-dynamodb

We are using NodeJS framework. I need to mock a dynamoDb insert function. I am not sure how to set this up and all the Google'd examples are for queries. Anyone help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you need something similar to https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamoose to connect nodejs and dynamoDB. This is a similar library to mongoose which is used for nodejs and mongodb connection. It just not only handles connection but it is an object modeling tool for Amazon's DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here for Put and batchwrite operations](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js/WorkingWithItems) samples from AWS. The node.js ones are in the midst of moving from v2 of the SDK to the newer v3 AWS JS SDK.